# Angular(5): two-way data binding on reusable form component?

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular(5), I'm trying to write a reusable group of form controls for a template driven form. It needs to be able to take a model from a parent component and pass it to the element for two-way data binding.

Here's what I have.

### admin-panel.component.ts (Parent Form)

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-panel',
  template: `
    <label>Settings</label>
    <!-- the below doesn't work, but is an example of how I'd like to use it -->
    <settings name="settings" [(ngModel)]="preset.settings"></settings>
`
})
export class AdminPanelComponent implements OnInit 
{
    preset;

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.preset = {
            name: '',
            settings: {
                settingOne: 'foo',
                settingTwo: false,
                settingThree: 14
            }
    }
}
```

### settings.component.html

For the ngModels below, I've also tried to set it like `model.settingOne`,`model.settingTwo`, but this didn't work either.

```
<div [ngModelGroup]="group">
    <select name="settingOne" [(ngModel)]="model.settingOne">
      <option value="foo">Foo</option>
      <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" name="settingTwo" [(ngModel)]="model.settingTwo">
</div>
```

### settings.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  viewProviders:[{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
})
export class SettingsComponent
{
  @Input('name') group: string;
  //@Input('model') model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. silly mistake. The above code indeed works with a couple minor changes.

First, in *admin-panel.component.ts*, replacing the line

```
<settings name="settings" [(ngModel)]="preset.settings"></settings>
```

with

```
<settings name="settings" [(model)]="preset.settings"></settings>
```

to match the input variable in *settings.component.ts* was on the right track.

But, it appeared to not work because in my form I had

`[ngFormOptions]="{ updateOn: 'submit' }"`, so nothing was getting updated. Removing that allowed the updates to come through.

Answer (score 0):

If one implements "[ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)" on any component then we can have two-way data binding automatically for your custom component.

Implementation [here](https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf)